# How to ignore "ifdef(TEST)" in Dialyzer?

Tags: erlang, dialyzer

I tried to use the define macro flag like this: `dialyzer -dNOTEST`, and it did not work. Does anyone have workaround?

Comment: Any specific case to explain?

Comment: I think voluntas can give us more detailed example of this issue.

Answer (score 3):

[The Dialyzer man page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html) says the `-D` option passes the argument to [erlc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlc.html). You can define a macro by the `-D` option, but *you cannot undefine one*. `-DNOTEST` will only define the macro `NOTEST`.

Comment: Yup, best route would probably be to compile it without the test flag to start with.